# Seaborn/Matplotlib graph not axis not displaying correct values

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm working on a data analysis project for a class and I'm running up against an issue I can't really solve. When I run code against a dataset and use Seaborn/Matplotlib to print a graph in a Jupyter Notebook, the X,Y Axis don't show the correct values. The X axis should be a range of movie budgets but instead counts up in 25 number increments and the Y axis is supposed to be a range of years going from 1960 out to 2015, but instead that axis is just labeled 1 thru 5 going out. What am I missing so that the graph adds in the budget and year range that I need.

Below is the code immediately before I print the graph. The code leading up to this is code that cleans and organizes the data.

[Screenshot from Jupyter Notebook of Seaborn code and graph with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKEvZ.jpg)
[Code and graph teaching how to use Seaborn and matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0s4S.jpg)

[GitHub repository with Jupyter Notebook: Investigate a Dataset](https://github.com/onpillow/Udacity-DAND-Term1/blob/master/p2/Investigate_a_Dataset.ipynb)

```
# Compute the Mean for budget vs. runtime
p_mean = df.groupby('budget').mean()['runtime']
p_mean.tail()

budget
260000000.0    116.
280000000.0    141.0
300000000.0    169.0
380000000.0    136.0
425000000.0    100.0
Name: runtime, dtype: float64

# build the index location for x-axis
index_mean = p_mean.index

#set style
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
#set x, y axis data
#x1, y1 for mean data; x2, y2 for median data
x1, y1 = index_mean, p_mean
#set size
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
#plot line chart for mean and median
plt.plot(x1, y1, color = 'r', label = 'mean')
#set title and labels
plt.title('Budget vs. Movie Runtime')
plt.xlabel('Budget')
plt.ylabel('Runtime');
#set legend
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The plot correctly plots the data. So if you are not satified with the data, you might want to share where it comes from and why you would expect it to be different.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This is my first ever attempt at data analysis so this follow up question might be silly but I feel like I'm missing a key link between the data I import into my notebook and how the graph labels each axis. I was expecting to see the monetary range of budgets from lowest to highest on the X axis and a range of movie runtimes from shortest to longest on the Y axis. I was basing my work on another person's notebook where they used the same dataset, but different columns from the CSV file. I just don't know why I'm not getting the same labeling on the graph.

Comment: They got the correct labels from their targeted data in the form of a decimal ranging from 0 -1.0 on the X axis and Years ranging from 1960 - 2015 on the Y axis. Using the same data set and the same code, I expected my axis labels and ranges to reflect the different data I was targeting and I don't know enough yet to know how to fix that or make sure the graph includes the right metrics on each axis. I'll post more screen shots and files if I can.

Comment: You have the series index, which contains values like 260000000 and that is plotted on the x axis, because you use `x1=index_mean = p_mean.index` as first argument to `plot`. You have the series values, which are values like 116 and that is plotted on the y axis because you use `y1 = p_mean` as second argument to `plot`. In your series there are neither values between 0 and 1, nor dates like 2015. So if you want to see those values on your axes you would need to use a different dataset.

Comment: I apologize, I believe I typed the wrong thing. The example I was using from someone else's JupNote was targeting data regarding Popularity and Year. I'm targeting data regarding Budget and Movie runtime. I'm trying to investigate if movie budget is correlated to movie runtime. I just uploaded another screenshot and the link to the original notebook I was pulling code from. I apologize if I'm messing this up and explaining things terribly. :(

Comment: Yeah, so there might be a slight correlation as it looks as cheeper movies run around 110 minutes, while the really expensive ones mostly run above 120 minutes. For a detailed analysis you would probably want to make a fit through the data.